# Generate Recamán's sequence

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, sequence

Recamán's sequence ([A005132](http://oeis.org/A005132)) is a mathematical sequence, defined as such:

```
A(0) = 0
A(n) = A(n-1) - n if A(n-1) - n > 0 and is new, else
A(n) = A(n-1) + n
```

A pretty LaTex version of the above (might be more readable):

$$A(n) = \begin{cases}0 & \textrm{if } n = 0 \\
A(n-1) - n & \textrm{if } A(n-1) - n \textrm{ is positive and not already in the sequence} \\
% Seems more readable than
%A(n-1) - n & \textrm{if } A(n-1) > n \wedge \not\exists m < n: A(m) = A(n-1)-n \\
A(n-1) + n & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The first few terms are `0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11`

To clarify, `is new` means whether the number is already in the sequence.

Given an integer `n`, via function argument or STDIN, return the first `n` terms of the Recamán sequence.

---

This is a code-golf challenge, so **shortest code wins.**

Comment: What does 'is new' mean?

Comment: If a number is new, it means it is not yet in the sequence. Just realized I have typed out the sequence wrong, give me a min to correct it.

Comment: Corrected the sequence.

Comment: Can you add the first values of the sequence?

Comment: Added the first few numbers! (And a link to its OEIS page)

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
0ali{_W=_I-__0<4$@#)|@I+@?+}fI1>`
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo '0ali{_W=_I-__0<4$@#)|@I+@?+}fI1>`') <<< 33
[0 1 3 6 2 7 13 20 12 21 11 22 10 23 9 24 8 25 43 62 42 63 41 18 42 17 43 16 44 15 45 14 46]
```

#### How it works

```
0ali                               " Push S := [ 0 ] and read an integer N from STDIN.    ";
    {                      }fI     " For each I in [ 0 ... (N - 1) ]:                     ";
     _W=                           "   X := S[-1].                                        ";
        _I-                        "   Y := X - I                                         ";
            _0<                    "   A := (Y < 0)                                       ";
           _   4$@#)               "   B := (Y ∊ S)                                       ";
                     @I+           "   Z := X + I                                         ";
                    |   @?         "   C := (A || B) ? Z : Y                              ";
                          +        "   S += [C]                                           ";
                              1>`  " Push str(S[1:]).                                     ";
```

Comment: What change did you make?

Comment: My first approach prepended negative numbers to the sequence, so I didn't have to explicitly check if `A(i) - i > 0`. However, I didn't prepend enough numbers for small values of `n`. Now, I just do exactly what the spec says.

Comment: 33 vs. 45. So close and yet so far. :)

Comment: Wow, comment without `e#` in Cjam... tasty cherry.

Answer (score 11):

## Hexagony, 212 bytes

```
?\..$@.=.'">'_<>}/..&\_.._!\.\].\"&"&=(<_...>\[.+.<_$|_...{.|.....}'.../<..|&.....'/..".>$/{.<\.\$\>\._?...><?$$.\[._\_}$&..~.|"$\./..{&_$....$'.|_...$}|_.-..;_....'}".'...2.....$?&....3..=.<_.....?.-+{......}\</$.}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5NCgIxDIXPYgmtIH4DCm7stN7DSHAhutKtMlOvPrY1i4QX3t/j9r7eX8/PsmQFOTESXAoWUxnAq4GtlAvqvPPjOtYH6cyGaDI3MDHTpoS6hgiz7zhUvSPJMBEVFU2K5aaOWYQzplakcr/MTpRKn7xJk0qgW0upZwtH64bF0TJ23V5yj9lTG/dSkNluJv5lNA5CWZbDDw)

**Input:** a single, positive integer \$n\$ on `stdin`.

**Output:** all terms of Recaman's sequence up to and including \$A(n)\$, separated by spaces (note that this means the program will print a total of \$n + 1\$ terms).

## Expanded

[image: expanded]

## Explanation

Apologies if this is confusing, but it's my first time with Hexagony, so rest assured that it confuses me too.

Let \$n = 6\$.
The instruction pointer (IP) starts out in the NW corner, moving along the black path.
`?` reads \$n\$ from `stdin` and stores it in the current memory edge.
Next, we copy \$n\$ three times while backing up the memory pointer.
We also flip the memory pointer and decrement the edge it points to.

```
"&"&"&=(
```

The IP eventually wraps around to the upper left corner again, jumping over `\` and looping through the rest of the black path.
This loop continues until the current edge is 0, at which point the graph looks like so:

[image: initialized]

This forms the skeleton of our memory layout.
Each `vertical` edge now stores a value \$i\$ from 0 to 6; later, these same edges will store the terms \$A(i)\$ of the sequence as they are computed.
Each `vertical` edge also has 4 contiguous edges that are used for later computations.  Let's explain them now:

- `head` is used for several purposes, but never to store anything permanently because it is frequently overwritten by other operations.
- `tail` is generally used as a temporary variable, but it remains 0 for the last \$i\$ in the sequence, telling the program when to stop.
- `prev` stores the value of \$A(i - 1)\$
- `copy` straightforwardly stores a copy of \$i\$ or, later, \$A(i)\$

Once the program is done initializing its memory graph, it branches off the black path and onto the red path near the NE corner.
First, `!` prints the decimal representation of `vertical` to `stdout`.
Next, we move the memory pointer to `tail` and test for zero:

```
'<
```

If it is zero, `@` terminates the program immediately; otherwise, we move to `head` and set it to 32 (an ASCII space):

```
}=}?32
```

[image: space]

`;` then prints this space to `stdout`.
Finally, we copy `vertical` to the next `prev`:

```
"?&"&
```

[image: cvp]

Now that the memory pointer is on the next term, we copy this term's `vertical` to *its* `copy` before moving to *its* `vertical`:

```
'&{=
```

[image: cvc]

`-` computes `prev` - `copy`, which is really \$A(i - 1) - i\$, and stores it in `vertical`:

[image: subtraction]

If `vertical` is not positive, `<` deflects the IP onto the green path, where `+` instead computes `prev` + `copy` (\$A(i - 1) + i\$) and stores it in `vertical`:

[image: addition]

The IP then wraps around to the SW corner, eventually returning to the beginning of the red path and starting the cycle over again.

However, if `vertical` is positive, we have to make sure it doesn't already exist in the sequence before printing it.
In this case, the `<` in the SE corner branches to the SE, wrapping around and staying on the red path.
First, we copy `vertical` to `head`:

```
"?&
```

This puts the memory pointer in a position so that successive loops can enter at the next `|` mirror.
Next, we copy `head` to the previous term's `tail` and move to *its* `head`.

```
"?&'
```

`-` computes `vertical` - `tail` (\$A(i - 1) - A(i)\$) and stores it in `head`.
Hexagony treats zero as a negative number, so we have to do some convoluted branching to test if `head` is exactly zero.
All that's necessary to know is that if `head` is zero, we've found a duplicate term, and the program will branch onto the yellow path.
Otherwise, it will return to the red path at the `{` instruction.

If `head` is zero, we return to the latest term of the sequence with `[`, which executes the subroutine along the pink and blue paths, before `+` computes \$A(i - 1) + i\$) like above.
We then return to the red path.

If `head` is not zero, we check if the current term is zero:

```
{<
```

If it is, we call the subroutine and go back to the red path through a convoluted series of mirrors.
If it isn't, we move to compare the next term, returning to the aforementioned `|` mirror.

---

Images created using Timwi's [Hexagony Colorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer) and [Esoteric IDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE).

Comment: For what its worth, your image with colored paths seems to show  that the curly bracket at the end doesn't do anything, you should be able to remove it and the preceding space for an easy -2.

Comment: thanks, just nice

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby, <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```
f=->n{a=[0];(n-1).times{|i|a+=[[b=a[-1]-i-1]-a!=[]&&b>0?b:b+2*i+2]};a}
```

A very "word-for-word" implementation of the definition.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 74

```hs
l=0:0#1
a§v|a<0||a`elem`r v=v|1<2=0-v
a#b=a+(a-b)§b:l!!b#(b+1)
r=(`take`l)
```

Example usage:

```hs
λ> r 20
[0,1,3,6,2,7,13,20,12,21,11,22,10,23,9,24,8,25,43,62]
```

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, <s>78</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 69 Bytes

Kudos to xnor and flornquake
Now almost 10 bytes shorter than the initial answer

```
m=p,=0,
exec"p+=1;k=m[-1]-p;m+=k+2*p*(k*(k>0)in m),;"*input()
print m
```

Comment: You can shorten `[k,k+2*p][bool]` to 
`k+2*p*(bool)`.

Comment: Also, `k in m or k<0` can be `k*(k>=0)in m` since if `k<0`, the product is `0`, which is in `m`.

Comment: You can write `-1` instead of `p-1`.  Edit: You can also make `m` a tuple and write `m=0,` and `m+=k+2*p*(k*(k>0)in m),`.

Comment: You can then change the first line to `m=p,=0,` and increment `p` at the start of the loop to save another character.

Comment: @flornquake Thank you. I did not know that `[-1]` returns the last element. I learned something today.

Comment: "m+=k+2*p*(k*(k>0)in m" < that is very interesting trick!

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript (41 <s>45</s>)

Try it [online here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzEwMAooLDEsXHs6fjEkPX4pLTpeMTxcLl4%2FKSEhQHxeXHt%2BKTIqK30qK30vYA%3D%3D):

```
(,1,\{:~1$=~)-:^1<\.^?)!!@|^\{~)2*+}*+}/
```

### Explanation

This is for the original 45 bytes solution, but it's still pretty much the same:

```
(,              # push array [0 .. n-1]
[0]\            # push sequence elements as [0] and reverse stack
{               # foreach element in [0 .. n-1] do:
  :m;           # store current element in m and discard
  .m=           # get the previous sequence element
  m)-:^         # subtract the current index from it and store in ^
  0>            # is that number greater than 0?
  \.^?)!        # is that number new to our sequence?
  @&            # logically and both checks
  {^}           # if true, push ^
  {^m)2*+}      # otherwise, add the index twice and push
  if
  +             # add new element to our sequence
}/
`               # make output pretty
```

*Edit #1:* Thanks to Dennis for shaving off 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 46 bytes

```
sn[z+z+d0r:a]sF0[pz-d1>Fd;a0<Fddd:azln!<M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2rwvzgvukq7SjvFoMgqMbbYzSC6oEo3xdDOLcU60cDGLSUlxSqxKidP0cY3NqXYt@L/fwA)

This program takes input from an otherwise empty stack and outputs to stdout (newline delimited).

I'm really proud of this one - it's beating everything that isn't a dedicated golfing language, and showcases three of my favorite dc golfing tricks:

- Stack size used as an index variable
- Refactoring "if A then B else C" into "unconditionally C, and if A then D" where C and D combine to make B
- the little-used random access array feature to solve a uniqueness constraint

## Explanation

```
sn             Stores the input in register n
[z+z+0r:a]sF   Defines the macro F, which: 
    z+z+         adds twice the stack size/index variable
    0r:a         resets the "uniqueness" flag to 0 in the array a
               In context, F is the "D" in my description above, 
               changing A(z-1)-z to A(z-1)+z
0              The main loop starts with the previous sequence member on top of 
               the stack and total stack depth equal to the next index. 
               Pushing a zero accomplishes both of these things.
[              Start of the main loop M
  p               Print the previous sequence member, with newline (no pop)
  z-             Calculate A(z-1)-z
  d1>F           If that's nonpositive, (F)ix it to be A(z-1)+z
  d;a            a is my array of flags to see if we've hit this value before
  0<F            If we have, (F)ix it! (nonzero = flag, since ;a is zero by
                 default, and also zero if we just (F)ixed and therefore 
                 don't care about uniqueness right now)
  ddd            Make one copy to keep and two to eat
  :a             Flag this entry as "used" in the uniqueness array a
  zln!<M         If our "index variable" is n or less, repeat!
]dsMx          End of main loop - store it and execute
```

Comment: that's wild, i had no idea dc even existed

Comment: really very nice. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript -  <s>81 80 79</s> 70

Kudos to edc65 for helping me save 9 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>{for(a=[x=i=0];++i<n;)a[i]=x+=x>i&a.indexOf(x-i)<0?-i:i;return a}
```

Comment: -9 :g=n=>{for(a=[x=i=0];++i<n;)a[i]=x+=x>i&a.indexOf(x-i)<0?-i:i;return a}

Comment: @edc65 Grazie mille :)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, ES6, <s>74</s> 69 characters

Run the below code in latest Firefox's Web Console.

```
G=n=>(i=>{for(r=[t=0];++i<n;)r[i]=t+=i>t|~r.indexOf(t-i)?i:-i})(0)||r
```

Will try to golf it more later.

Example usage:

```
G(11) -> 0,1,3,6,2,7,13,20,12,21,11
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, <s>83</s> 78 Bytes

Save the below as `f.m` (73 Bytes)

```
A=0;for i=1:n-1 b=A(i)-i;A(i+1)=b+2*i;if b>0&&~any(A==b) A(i+1)=b;end;end
```

Run from command window (5 bytes)

```
n=9;f
```

If the above is not legal, then it requires 90 bytes.

```
function A=f(n) 
A=0;for i=1:n-1 b=A(i)-i;A(i+1)=b+2*i;if b>0&&~any(A==b) A(i+1)=b;end;end
```

Answer (score 3):

## R: 96 characters

Golfed:

```
A=function(s,n,m,i){if(m==n){return(s)}else{t=i-m;if(t%in%s||t<0){t=i+m};s=c(s,t);A(s,n,m+1,t)}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
A = function(s,n,m,i) {
    if(m==n){return(s)}
    else{
        t=i-m
        if(t%in%s||t<0){t=i+m}
        s=c(s,t)
        A(s,n,m+1,t)
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
> An(0,34,1)
[1]   0   1   3   6   2   7  13  20  12  21  11  22  10  23   9  24   8
[18]  25  43  62  42  63  41  18  42  17  43  16  44  15  45  14  46  79
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 63 bytes

```
n=>(g=y=>n-x?g(a[++x]=a.includes(z=y-x)|z<0?+y+x:z):a)(a=[x=0])
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFtCoMwDADQ6yR0DTLYH1mUnUNlBr@ouFR0G23Z3bv3VvnKORxuf1v145RnzsoVLBy5UhvqBaQxJnQs5HTYPuN0QuJoA/7SvahNNKFMWAqCcBO46DAPXk@/TbT5BRoiehyHRLjesKOX7ADPi0OuZnCItHqnfas95j8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
¾ˆG¯¤N-DŠD0›*åN·*+ˆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//8K@y4ZHwq/CpE4tRMWgRDDigLoqw6VOwrcqK8uG//81MA)

**Explanation**

```
¾ˆ                    # Initialize the global list with 0
  G                   # for N in [1, input-1] do:
   ¯                  # push the global list
    ¤N-               # subtract N from the last item in the list
       D              # duplicate
        Š             # move the copy down 2 spots on the stack
         D            # duplicate again
          0›          # check if it is positive
            *         # multiply, turning negative results to zero
             å        # is the result already present in the list?
              N·*     # multiply by N*2
                 +    # add to the result
                  ˆ   # add this to the list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>62</s> 57 bytes

<s>{(0,{$*-@*+@**2*($*!>@*||$*-@*∈@*)given @*[*-1]}...*)[^$*]}</s>

```
{(0,{($!=@_[*-1])+@_-@_*2*($!>@_&&$!-@_∉@_)}...*)[^$_]}
```

*-5 bytes thanks to Jo King*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAp1pDRdHWIT5aS9cwVlPbIV7XIV7LSAsoaOcQr6amogjkP@rodIjXrNXT09PSjI5TiY@t/V@cWKmQpmFqoPkfAA)

Comment: that's amazing... that literally looks like my cat walked across my keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 53 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{$[y>c:#x;o[x,(r;*|x+c)(r in x)|0>r:*|x-c;y];x]}[,0;]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1olutIu2Uq5wjo/ukJHo8haq6ZCO1lTo0ghM0@hQrPGwK7ICiikm2xdGWtdEVsbrWNgbWgY@/8/AA)

**Explanation:**

Recursive solution.

```
{$[y>c:#x;o[x,(r;*|x+c)(r in x)|0>r:*|x-c;y];x]}[,0;] / the solution
{                                              }[,0;] / lambda with first arg set as list containing 0
 $[      ;                                  ; ]       / if[condition;true;false]
       #x                                             / length of x
     c:                                               / save as c
   y>                                                 / y greater than? (ie have we produced enough results?)
                                             x        / return x if we are done
          o[                             ;y]          / recurse with new x and existing y
                                      x-c             / subtract c from x
                                    *|                / reverse first, aka last
                                  r:                  / save result as r
                                0>                    / 0 greater than?
                               |                      / or
                       (      )                       / do together
                        r in x                        / r in x?
              ( ;     )                               / use result to index into this 2-item list
                   x+c                                / add c to x
                 *|                                   / reverse first, aka last 
               r                                      / result
            x,                                        / append to x
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
(,][`(+2*#)@.(e.+.0>[)~{:-#)^:(]`0:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NXRioxM0tI20lDUd9DRS9bT1DOyiNeuqrXSVNeOsNGITDKw0/2typSZn5CukKRga/AcA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
n=a=0
v=[]
exec'a+=[n,-n][a+n in v];print a;n-=1;v+=a,n;'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQvadwZ6WCtpU5ibgYQsjNT8KkTj@9179xXthFQExBTcpF1bcehi1lOI@S2UI36FlSvxuG5gRPMU1L7JDM1tCfsawiMfw)

Avoids negative numbers by adding them to the list of already visited numbers.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 144

```
int[]f(int n){int[]a=new int[n];a[0]=0;int i,j,k,m;for(i=0;i<n-1;){k=a[i++]-i;m=0;for(j=0;j<i;)if(k==a[j++])m=1;a[i]=m<1&k>0?k:k+2*i;}return a;}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lua - <s>141 135 139</s> 135

```
function s(n)a,b={1},{[0]=0}for i=1,n do k=b[i-1]-i c=k+i+i if(k>0)and(a[k]==nil)then b[i],a[k]=k,1 else b[i],a[c]=c,1 end end return b end
```

readable version:

```
function s(n)
a,b={1},{[0]=0}
for i=1,n do 
   k=b[i-1]-i 
   c=k+i+i
   if (k>0) and (a[k]==nil) then 
      b[i],a[k]=k,1 
   else 
      b[i],a[c]=c,1
   end 
end 
return b 
end
```

I use 2 tables, the first one is called *a* and it is built so that a[i]=1 iff *i* has already appeared in the sequence, *nil* otherwise, while the second table actually holds the sequence

Comment: Your sequence should start with 0, though

Comment: You're right, I didn't look at the question very carefully and assumed it had the same definition at mathworld (starting with 1), I think that won't cost any more character, I'll test and correct it later, I'm writing from my phone now!

Answer (score 2):

#### Powershell (103)

```
$n=Read-Host;$a=@(0);$n-=1;1..$n|%{$x=$a[-1]-$_;if($x-gt0-and!($a-like$x)){$a+=$x}else{$a+=$x+2*$_}};$a
```

Another 'word-for-word' implementation down here as well. Surprisingly readable for PowerShell, too.

Sequence is stored in the array $a, and printed out one term per line.

For $n=20 if we run the statement `$a-join","` we get

```
0,1,3,6,2,7,13,20,12,21,11,22,10,23,9,24,8,25,43,62
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 73

```
def f(x,t=0):
 if x:t=f(x-1);t+=2*x*(t*(t>0)in map(f,range(x)))
 return t
```

Edit 1: Thanks to @xnor's tips on the other Python answer!
(I just realised that both look very similar.)

Edit 2: Thanks again, @xnor.

Comment: This gives an infinite loop. You need some sort of control flow so that `f(x)` doesn't always immediately call `f(x-1)`.

Comment: @xnor fixed the code.

Comment: This seems to return the nth term, not the first n terms.

Comment: Some minor saves: `t=0` can go as an optional parameter to `f`, and `t=t+` can be `t+=`.

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy : <strike>122</strike> <strike>118</strike> 111 chars

Golfed:

```
m=args[0] as int
a=[0]
(1..m-1).each{n->b=a[n-1];x=b-n;(x>0&!(x in a))?a[n]=x:(a[n]=b+n)}
a.each{print "$it "}
```

Ungolfed:

```
m = args[0] as int
a = [0]
(1..m-1).each { n->
    b = a[n-1]
    x = b-n
    ( x>0 & !(x in a) ) ? a[n] = x : (a[n] = b+n) 
}
a.each{print "$it "}
```

Sample Run:

```
bash$ groovy Rec.groovy 14
0 1 3 6 2 7 13 20 12 21 11 22 10 23
```

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure : 174 chars

Golfed:

```
(defn f[m a](let[n(count a)b(last a)x(- b n)y(if(and(> x 0)(not(.contains a x)))x(+ b n))](if(= m n)a(f m(conj a y)))))(println(f(read-string(first *command-line-args*))[0]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn f[m a]
  (let [n (count a) 
        b (last a) 
        x (- b n) 
        y (if (and (> x 0) (not (.contains a x))) x (+ b n)) ]
    (if (= m n) a (f m (conj a y))) ) )

(println (f (read-string (first *command-line-args*)) [0]) )
```

Sample run:

```
bash$ java -jar clojure-1.6.0.jar rec.clj 14 
[0 1 3 6 2 7 13 20 12 21 11 22 10 23]
```

Comment: I suggest you not to read from STDIN but instead just take an integer argument to the function :) Also you don't get any benefits from defining `y` on the `let` form, you can use the expression directly where the value is needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathcad, 54 "bytes"

[image]

---

From user perspective, Mathcad is effectively a 2D whiteboard, with expressions evaluated from left-to-right,top-to-bottom. Mathcad does not support a conventional "text" input, but instead makes use of a combination of text and special keys / toolbar / menu items to insert an expression, text, plot or component. For example, type ":" to enter the definition operator (shown on screen as ":=") or "ctl-shft-#" to enter the for loop operator (inclusive of placeholders for the iteration variable, iteration values and one body expression). What you see in the image above is exactly what appears on the user interface and as "typed" in.

For golfing purposes, the "byte" count is the equivalent number of keyboard operations required to enter an expression.

Comment: That's all [well and good](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4816/76162), but what *are* the actual keystrokes?

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>116 111</s> 109 bytes

```c
*f(n){int*a=calloc(4,n),i=0,j,k,m;for(;~i+n;a[i]=k+(m|k<1)*2*i)for(k=a[i++]-i,m=0,j=i;j--;)m=k-a[j]?m:1;n=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NDoIwEITvPsVKYtLfBIgnl8YHIRyaGsxSWwjiCfHVsdXTZL7Z2V2n787tu@hZ5CvFRVjj7OMxOnZWkSsypRqUVwH7cWb4IRnRttQZL1l4@6biohbEc@hNCqTsNKmQW4Zw0Bp5MF7bduiu4VJhNBa3Pd2BYCkyvh4AshMWDPSsqoFjQnnfj1PCJSZpoKqTSgkccglgmtNAz6BQp1shj6QgP/bvbzC9licriuS2/Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 89 bytes

```php
$f=function($n){for(;$i<$n;$s[$r[$i++]=$p=$m]=1)if($s[$m=$p-$i]|0>$m)$m=$p+$i;return$r;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjLCsIwEEbhV@nih86QCnXlYhp9kJJVTeiAuRDblfrssbo5cL6yljbdylEEG/a0bJoTIfEr5EoCnZAEzxl1hhrjLIpFdPbMGujn8ZAT1L3HKyL/10Cl@m2vCVU@0vyy5k5jeeS7p37ohw6BLiOztC8)

Ungolfed:

```php
$f = function ($n) {
    for (; $i < $n; $s[$r[$i++] = $p = $m] = 1) {
        if ($s[$m = $p - $i] | 0 > $m) {
            $m = $p + $i;
        }
    }

    return $r;
};
```

- `$r` for my result
- `$s` for tracking seens
- `$p` previous value
- `$m` *m*ext value

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
É╖C8½ΔL▄░▬L+≡ΩSa⌂¼╧
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=90b74338abff4cdcb0164c2bf0ea53617faccf&i=3%0A100&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.  It keeps the sequence so far on the stack, and remembers `A(n - 1)` in the X register.  The iteration index is used for `n`.  The first time through, it's 0, but in that iteration it generates the 0 without any special cases, so there's no need to adjust for the off-by-1 index.

```
0X      push 0 to main stack and store it in X register, which will store A(n - 1)
z       push an empty array that will be used to store the sequence
,D      pop input from input stack, execute the rest of the program that many times
  xi-Y  push (x-register - iteration-index) and store it in the Y register
        this is (A(n - 1) - n)
  0>    test if (A(n - 1) - n) is greater than 0 (a)
  ny#   count number of times (A(n - 1) - n) occurs in the sequence so far (b)
  >     test if (a) > (b)
    y   (A(n - 1) - n)
    xi+ A(n - 1) + n
  ?     if/else;  choose between the two values based on the condition
  X     store the result in the X register
  Q     print without popping
  +     append to sequence array
```

[Run and debug this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=0X+++++%09push+0+to+main+stack+and+store+it+in+X+register,+which+will+store+A%28n+-+1%29%0Az++++++%09push+an+empty+array+that+will+be+used+to+store+the+sequence%0A,D+++++%09pop+input+from+input+stack,+execute+the+rest+of+the+program+that+many+times%0A++xi-Y+%09push+%28x-register+-+iteration-index%29+and+store+it+in+the+Y+register%0A+++++++%09this+is+%28A%28n+-+1%29+-+n%29%0A++0%3E+++%09test+if+%28A%28n+-+1%29+-+n%29+is+greater+than+0+%28a%29%0A++ny%23++%09count+number+of+times+%28A%28n+-+1%29+-+n%29+occurs+in+the+sequence+so+far+%28b%29%0A++%3E++++%09test+if+%28a%29+%3E+%28b%29%0A++++y++%09%28A%28n+-+1%29+-+n%29%0A++++xi%2B%09A%28n+-+1%29+%2B+n%0A++%3F++++%09if%2Felse%3B++choose+between+the+two+values+based+on+the+condition%0A++X++++%09store+the+result+in+the+X+register%0A++Q++++%09print+without+popping%0A++%2B++++%09append+to+sequence+array&i=3%0A100&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 31 bytes

```pyth
VQ=+Y?Y?|>NeYhxY-eYN+eYN-eYNZ)Y
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Welcome. Code-only answers are discouraged because they tend to be automatically flagged as low-quality. Add an explanation, and consider adding a link to an online interpreter, like this: https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzQVjvSPtK@xs4vNTKjIlI3NdJPG4hBdJRm5P//hoYA

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)!
-2 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!

```ruby
->n{v,*d=0;n.times{|i|d<<v+=v<i||d!=d-[v-i]?i:-i};d}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur7pMRyvF1sA6T68kMze1uLomsybFxqZM27bMJrOmJkXRNkU3ukw3M9Y@00o3s9Y6pfZ/gUJatKFh7H8A)

**Commented**:

```ruby
->n{ ... }                         # lambda function taking an integer
  v,*d=0                           # initialize list of sequence values d and previous value v
  n.times{|i| ... }                # run the following code for i = 0,1,...,n-1:
          v<i||d!=d-[v-i]?i:-i     #   i IF (v < i OR d != (d without v-i)) ELSE -i
       v+=                         #   add this to v
    d<<                            #   and append the new value of v to d
  d                                # return d
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, 29 bytes

```
00000034: 89 fe 31 c0 99 eb 11 29 d0 78 0a 60 89 f7 89 d1  ..1....).x.`....
00000044: f2 af 61 75 03 8d 04 50 ab 42 e2 eb c3           ..au...P.B...
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl recaman
        // input: ECX: n, EDI: u32[n]
        // output: stored to EDI
recaman:
        // Save the array pointer to ESI
        mov     esi, edi
        // EAX (A(n)) = 0
        xor     eax, eax
        // EDX (n) = 0
        cdq
        // Store first word
        jmp     .Lstore
.Lloop:
        // A(n - 1) - n
        sub     eax, edx
        // if negative, do A(n - 1) + n
        js      .Lneg_or_dup
.Lnot_neg_or_dup:
        // We need to save both EDI and ECX, so we do a lazy PUSHA/POPA.
        pusha
        // EDI = start of array
        mov     edi, esi
        // ECX = current output length
        mov     ecx, edx
        // Search for A(n - 1) - n
        repnz   scasd
        // restore registers
        popa
        // If the zero flag is set, we found a match.
        // If not, go directly to store
        jnz     .Lstore
.Lneg_or_dup:
        // Convert A(n - 1) - n to A(n - 1) + n by adding n * 2
        // EAX = EAX + EDX * 2
        lea     eax, [eax + 2 * edx]
.Lstore:
        // Store a u32 to EDI and autoincrement
        stosd
        // Increment length
        inc     edx
        // Decrement counter and loop if non zero
        loop    .Lloop
        // Return
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVtT9swEP6eX3HqtCmB8NIi7UMZSAiQVglpCDQNCaHI2E4alNiZ7ZQWxF9fd3bSJKbQD0lzb7577rkzraq9jNL1l1zQomYcflBtWC5Pg3cSYd6JVC6y0yDgS8OVgNH5KFjInIHilJREJJRxWoTodjRJDOwQpWLYfBVcZGYeHQdBkhBdJkl4MwrX0P720YwXiV4JQ5YgZKV4mi@DTp0V8rHYnNOJDw4wfFWbKVye301BxHB5MZtCfTS5Fw9DK1kbZ6aNVJyBkdYwaMNNh5a3ZMHBzDlg8mQFlbSJKedxO@sMS7lwb67zGDjLhxEuz@4gPAtFFMEJHHaapVSNC1nG9uG5XKCL8O0p@@vlZTOHNFfawLNUrNM9lVUD0ZUrLti/KqSsvJowGdiDcYSPHjtdPw7yYV4@eQqCZ8TkCx4Dk32A3UGAJ9325gptE6kSVld4upAm6QVeHn84hm3g1xbmR2nmthFABLMdjEFLeOb2RAIFeVnB9e/bn2cH17@uz/a7QFWt58RHb4bIaUOUabq23SZm26T9Np3foRetleLCtATZdqTb4NxyougcUuznh8AqXokXCzAlmg0dFXcdwneWaySV7kuSlVfRLHUUfOFKQlqQDHINmpvYgpPKGtEiUBJD5/vvvBD8GDIJLEdum2LloHa06LrmchvS5ZNmnUux4IjosEYbbsgFeFwBYbgnMhA74/dDcOKeu47dOzDp1AUnPfPu8Yk2E7RAnB@CNq/pNveJnet2dB1jSG1wOqniJXaw57WRPuyzjUm7gjod@rbs8Pp7wTf2FKG2w28Ps0Pl5kIK15e@GqtwgNp/w0A33NRqyAsTDNVuWcKzIlWFZ4S10NQup@iTpdcs18D7mnpD0TJ9WzYgvjcR91xXiP148vAx8Tf6772ekqJoivE3cdWA4J3VyQY5WRC6@ogxm43f7Pt1NLIXBK5cpHcuQnu5RMFr0HSruUdwwu/Hhw/HTljyEucidBfN4TJNcYPkL1ymVhJFjY1/OTnT8WGrs0Pc3VffljC14SN47WvAG8@k4egri2EUw7L1ewvegvU/amdTr/fKo8l/)

The input is a pointer to an `int32_t` array of `n` elements in `edi`, with `n` being in `ecx`.

The output will be stored into `edi`.

Answer (score 1):

## C#: 140 characters

```
int i,w,t,y;int[]F(int n){var r=new int[n--];for(;i<n;y=0){w=r[i++]-i;for(t=0;y<i&&t<1;)t=w==r[y++]?1:0;r[i]=w>0&&t<1?w:r[i-1]+i;}return r;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++: 180 characters (158 without cin and cout statements)

```
int a[5000000][2]={0},i,k,l;a[0][0]=0;a[0][1]=1;cin>>k;for(i=1;i<=k;i++){l=a[i-1][0];if(l-i>0&&a[l-i][1]!=1){ a[i][0]=l-i;a[l-i][1]=1;}else{ a[i][0]=l+i;a[l+i][1]=1;}cout<<a[i][0]<<endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange! Please edit the character/byte count of your solution into your header, as shown in the other answers here. Also, please golf your code (ex. remove whitespace to reduce the character count) as much as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - 81 bytes

```
Fold[#~Append~(#[[-1]]+If[#[[-1]]>#2&&FreeQ[#,#[[-1]]-#2],-#2,#2])&,{0},Range@#]&
```

### Usage

```
Fold[#~Append~(#[[-1]]+If[#[[-1]]>#2&&FreeQ[#,#[[-1]]-#2],-#2,#2])&,{0},Range@#]&[30]
{0,1,3,6,2,7,13,20,12,21,11,22,10,23,9,24,8,25,43,62,42,63,41,18,42,17,43,16,44,15,45}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 103 bytes

```
proc A n {lappend L [expr {$n?[set x [lindex [set L [A [expr $n-1]]] e]]>$n&$x-$n ni$L?$x-$n:$x+$n:0}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUw5CsMwEPzKFEuaIIjaBGLc@wfKFsZWsUFZC1sBgfDbFdmkmYM50hRqjesyoYeihDFGrzMGOJ/jikLauc0nZLggOvvGh215/6@QGsvM8MxP0gtlQwoVGrpT3ilfG9523uuxFBj7QJKPR4nftMG9F9HzTnRaIe3qBd5hbf0B)

Answer (score 1):

### Common LISP (139 bytes)

```
(defun r(n)(do*(s(i 0(1+ i))(a 0(car s))(b 0(- a i)))((> i n)(nreverse s))(push(cond((= 0 i)0)((and(> b 0)(not(find b s)))b)(t(+ a i)))s)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defun recaman (n)
  (do*
   (series               ; starts as empty list
    (i 0 (1+ i))         ; index variable
    (last 0 (car s))     ; last number in the series
    (low 0 (- last i)))

   ((> i n)              ; exit condition
    (nreverse series))   ; return value

    (push                ; loop body
     (cond
       ((= 0 i) 0)       ; first pass
       ((and
         (> low 0) (not (find low s)))
        low)
       (t (+ last i)))
     series)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, <s>154</s> 139 bytes

This is pretty big, but I like that it only uses one comparison per iteration instead of the 2 given, thanks to Saturating Subtraction generating a 0 if a[n-1]-n would be less than 0; and since 0 is already the first element, every would-be negative is saturated to 0 and is detected instead by the 'A already contains' comparison. Also... the size is not bad compared to Clojure, C#, C++, Common Lisp, lua..

```
fn r(n:usize)->Vec<usize>{let mut a=vec![0usize;n];for i in 1..n{a[i]=if a.contains(&(a[i-1].saturating_sub(i))){a[i-1]+i}else{a[i-1]-i}}a}
```

ungolfed

```
fn r(n:usize)->Vec<usize>{
  let mut a=vec![0usize;n];
  for i in 1..n {
     a[i] = if a.contains(&(a[i-1].saturating_sub(i)))     
            {a[i-1]+i} else {a[i-1]-i}
 }a}
```

[Try it on the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75f6e6491fd595b479c5d2ed167fb799)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 122 bytes

```
(setf h(make-hash-table)n(read)j 0)(dotimes(i n)(when(or(<(decf j i)0)#1=(gethash j h))(incf j(+ i i)))(print(setf #1#j)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsMgEER/ZcHLLCVgem4/xsZNd21iggr9fGvocd68YZbN6tk7qrSVFHv4yKSh6tTCaxPOKBIiJ/KMeDTbpcIoM74qGUfBA1GWlRIZe3bzE29p134QZYblq8SNbAgjn8Vy@5@52VEarPe7/wE)

The sequence is generated by from 0, the values are stored in a hash table. Here is the ungolfed version:

```
(setf h (make-hash-table)         ; create a hash table to store the results
      n (read)                    ; read the input in n
      j 0)                        ; initial value of the sequence
(dotimes (i n)                    ; loop for i from 0 below n
  (when (or (< (decf j i) 0)      ; the new value is the old - i; if negative
            (gethash j h))        ; or if the value has been already generated
    (incf j (+ i i)))             ; set j to A(n-1) + i (third case)
  (print (setf (gethash j h) j))) ; store the result in the table and print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#, <s>117</s> 116 bytes

```
fun n->Seq.fold(fun(l:'a list)h->let a=l.[h-1]in if a-h>0&&not(Seq.contains(a-h)l)then l@[a-h]else l@[a+h])[0][1..n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 bytes

```perl
push@a,($t=$a[-1]-$_)+($t<0||grep$t==$_,@a)*$_*2for 0..<>;say"@a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gtDjDIVFHQ6XEViUxWtcwVlclXlMbyLUxqKlJL0otAErYqsTrOCRqaqnEaxml5RcpGOjp2dhZFydWKjkkKv3/b2TyL7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
tu+G-eG_W|g0J-eGH}JGHQ]0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6RU21031T0@vCbdwAvI8Kj1cvcIjDX4/9/QAAA)

```
tu+G-eG_W|g0J-eGH}JGHQ]0   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
 u                   Q     Reduce [0-Q)...
                      ]0   ... with initial value G=[0], next value as H:
              eG             Last value of G (sequence so far)
             -  H            Take H from the above
            J                Store in J
          g0J                0 >= J
                 }JG         Is J in G?
         |                   Logical OR of two previous results
       _W           H        If the above is true, negate H, otherwise leave as positive
    -eG                      Subtract the above from last value in G
  +G                         Append the above to G
                           The result of the reduction is the sequence with an extra leading 0
t                          Remove a leading 0, implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```hs
f 0=[0]
f n|x<-g n,y<-last x=x++[last$y-n:[y+n|y<n||y-n`elem`x]]
g=f.pred
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FccxCoAgGAbQvVN8Q5sZtoaeRISE1CT7iWpQ8O5W23ubvXeXUmseQmlhOg@qWfIAGorkyd4PssqM6Z994TTrwqgWSbV@W1xyx5KN6YLy43m5tR02EhTOK9KDHgGTaC8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
_Ṫ»0ḟ⁸ȯ+Ṫ⁸;
Ḷç/
```

A monadic Link that accepts a **positive** integer, \$n\$, and yields a list of non-negative integers, the first \$n\$ terms of \$A\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4c5Vh3YbPNwx/1HjjhPrtYFcIMOa6@GObYeX6////9/UAgA)**

#### How?

```
_Ṫ»0ḟ⁸ȯ+Ṫ⁸; - Link 1, next prefix of Recamán: list, current_prefix; integer, next_n
                                  (1st call is actually made with current_prefix=0)
_           - (current_prefix) subtract (next_n)  -> [A(0)-n...,A(n-1)-n] (or A(0)-n when current_prefix=0)
 Ṫ          - tail                                -> A(n-1)-n
  »0        - maximum of that and zero            -> 0 or A(n-1)-n
    ḟ⁸      - filter discard if in current_prefix -> [] or [A(n-1)-n]
       +    - (current_prefix) add (next_n)       -> [A(0)+n...,A(n-1)+n] (or A(0)+n when current_prefix=0)
      ȯ     - (filtered) logical OR (added)       -> [A(n-1)-n] or [...,A(n-1)+n] (or A(0)+n when current_prefix=0)
        Ṫ   - tail                                -> A(n-1)-n or A(n-1)+n
         ⁸; - concatenate this to the current_prefix

Ḷç/ - Main Link: positive integer, n
Ḷ   - lowered range -> [0,1,2,...,n-1]
  / - reduce using:
 ç  -   last Link (Link 1) as a dyad
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>n--?[p+=p<k|g[p-k]?k:-k,...g(g[p]=k+1)]:[])(p=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBDkAwDADQ32lDFxwX5UOWHQRbqGwN4uTfxzu@fXqmaz43vSnlZS2BS@IBIgsPiWh0WrH28kanJH4US1IbYyL84VmqFr11HkG5wTLndOVjNUeOEKBrEMsH)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0λ£Nλ₁N-Dd*åi+ë-
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//zDOu8KjTs674oKBTi1EZCrDpWkrw6st//8xMQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
 λ              # Create a recursive environment
0               # which starts at a(0)=0
  £             # to output the first (implicit) input amount of values
                # (which will be output implicitly in the end)
                # and in each iteration, we calculate the next `a(n)` with:
     ₁          #  Push `a(n-1)`
      N-        #  Subtract the current `n`
        D       #  Duplicate this `a(n-1)-n`
         d      #  Check that it's non-negative (>= 0)
          *     #  Multiply it to `a(n-1)-n` (so it'll become 0 if it's negative)
    λ      åi   #  If it's in the list of previous [a(0), ..., a(n-1)] values:
   N         +  #   Add `n` to the implicit `a(n-1)`
            ë   #  Else:
   N         -  #   Subtract `n` from the implicit `a(n-1)` instead
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@TwXµY *!ZøX ªX+YÑ}h
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFR3WLVZICohWvhYIKpYK1nRfWg&input=MTE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>110</s> 81 bytes

```julia
[]|>v->0|>a->0:parse(Int,readline()).|>i->(println(a+=2(a-i in v)i-i);v=[v;a;~i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoQwEAXQq1jO4EaipcHpPYNYDGyKL2GQrAaLsFfP7ivecSfo@LS27VWKE19F/8@n5k@k1a5XjvpOsEjMQxU4oTPDrmSk/TKROnSwrjAcOJRlK0HDFzu3Nnr/Aw)

-29 thx to Steffan!

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoQwEAXQq1jO4EaipcHpPYNYDGyKL2GQrAaLsFfP7ivecSfo@LS27VWKE19F/8@n5k@k1a5XjvpOsEjMQxU4oTPDrmSk/TKROnSwrjAcOJRlK0HDFzu3Nnr/Aw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online"). Recursion is probably even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 108 bytes

```
T[]r(T)(T n){T[]a=[0];T[T]b;foreach(i;1..n+1){T x=a[$-1];x+=(x>i)&&!((x-i)in b)?-i:i;a~=x;b[x]=1;}return a;}
```

Uses a [function template](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html) [shortcut syntax](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates_more.html).

Try it online by pasting the following snippet to https://run.dlang.io/

```
T[]r(T)(T n){T[]a=[0];T[T]b;foreach(i;1..n+1){T x=a[$-1];x+=(x>i)&&!((x-i)in b)?-i:i;a~=x;b[x]=1;}return a;}
void main(){import std.stdio;writeln(r(10));}
```

Comment: Size reduced from 117 to 108 bytes by using a function template shortcut syntax.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 107 bytes

```
#(loop[s[0]i 1](if(= i %)s(recur(conj s(let[l(last s)N(- l i)](if(or(< N 0)((set s)N))(+ l i)N)))(inc i))))
```

Not many tricks here, `((set s)N)` evaluates to `N` if it is in the set and `nil` otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 40 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{⌽{⍵,⍨(((∊∘⍵∨≤∘0)r)×2×≢⍵)+r←(⊃-≢)⍵}⍣⍵⊢0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz97qR71bdR71rtDQ0HjU0fWoYwaQ/6hjxaPOJUC2gWaR5uHpRoenP@pcBBTX1C561DZB41FXsy5QQBMoUvuodzFIQ9cig9r/aQpAWYVHvX2P@qYCWUBlho/aJkM5fVOLi5KBZElGZjFQpbEBAA) <s>I will be back for some more golfing and to write an explanation, just give me some hours.</s> Ok I need some more time, in golfing this I managed to [make it longer](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz97qvEdtEzQedTXrPupcpPmod@uj7hYgqfOod0WetoaGxqOOrkcdM0DiHSsedS4Bsg008zQPTzc6PB2qofZR72KQfNcig9r/aQpA4xQe9fY96psKZAHNNXzUNhnK6ZtaXJQMJEsyMouBKo0NAA).

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz97qR71bdR71rnjU1ayhASSAXN0izTqQqO6j3s1FmkDJrdpFj9omPOpcBGTWPupdDKQedQE5a2r/p4Ekevse9U319AfqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwNgAA) (Changed `0` to `⍬` to match the challenge more closely)