# Recamán's duplicates

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

[Recamán's Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecamansSequence.html) is defined as follows:

\$a_n=\begin{cases}0\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{if n = 0}\\a_{n-1}-n\quad\text{if }a_{n-1}-n>0\text{ and is not already in the sequence,}\\a_{n-1}+n\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\$

or in pseudo-code:

```
a(0) = 0,
if (a(n - 1) - n) > 0 and it is not 
   already included in the sequence,
     a(n) = a(n - 1) - n 
else 
     a(n) = a(n - 1) + n.
```

The first numbers are ([OEIS A005132](https://oeis.org/A005132)):

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11, 22, 10, 23, 9, 24, 8, 25, 43, 62, 42, 63, 41, 18, 42
```

If you study this sequence, you'll notice that there are duplicates, for instance `a(20) = a(24) = 42` (0-indexed). We'll call a number a duplicate if there is at least one identical number in front of it in the sequence.

---

#### Challenge:

Take an integer input **k**, and output either the first **k** duplicate numbers in the order they are found as duplicates in Recamán's Sequence, or only the **k**'th number.

This first duplicated numbers are:

```
42, 43, 78, 79, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 152, 265, 261, 262, 135, 136, 269, 453, 454, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262
```

A few things to note:

- **a(n)** does not count as a duplicate if there are no identical numbers in **a(0) ... a(n-1)**, even if **a(n+m)==a(n)**.
- 42 will be before 43, since its duplicate occurs before 43's duplicate
- The sequence is not sorted
- There are duplicate elements in this sequence too. For instance the 12th and the 23rd numbers are both **262** (0-indexed).

---

#### Test cases (0-indexed)

```
k      Output
    0      42
    9     152
   12     262
   23     262
  944    5197
  945   10023
10000   62114
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in each language wins!

**Explanations are encouraged!**

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/generaterecam%C3%A1ns-sequence)

Comment: Why isn't `43` output before `42`? It appears first in Recamán's sequence. Do you mean output first the one that is first found to be a duplicate?

Comment: @LuisMendo As I understand it, \$43\$ should appear after \$42\$ because its duplicate occurrence is later on in the sequence (so the second occurrence of \$42\$ lies before the second occurrence of \$43\$).

Comment: I also, saw the popular math.SE question recently :P

Comment: @orlp huh? Can you link to it? I haven't seen it...

Comment: *There are duplicate elements in this sequence too. For instance the 12th and the 23rd numbers are both 262 (0-indexed).* Are there duplicates in *this* list of duplicate elements too? How deep does this rabbit hole go?

Comment: @StewieGriffin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827702/bijection-f-colon-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-with-f0-0-and-fn-fn-1-n

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I wouldn't be surprised if every single one of the top 100 users on this site could answer that better than me!

Comment: @StewieGriffin Nitpick: as of writing this, [you're in the first page](http://web.archive.org/web/20180627221510/https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) (note: yuck).

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>88</s> <s>85</s> 76 bytes

```
(For[i=k=j=p=0,k<#,i~FreeQ~p||k++,i=i|p;p+=If[p>++j&&FreeQ[i,p-j],-j,j]];p)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY67CsIwFED3@xWBlqLkFl9VkBoRB6HgoK4hQykp3tS2IcZBrP56fawO5yxnOXXuz7rOPRV5X4pBP9i1TpKohBFWjLFaBUivndP6@LJdV3GOJKizqeUiK6Vdc26i6NcloY2NwtigUSq1w6gfpgDbS1tU8hGedHFzV2qbPdXkmWBZU1JD/o4szLx2n4X/9kQGAAdHjZcBi9es3AQqYqMNwANggjAZf5ghTBOEZTL/agHwBFD9NHkD)

1-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
For[
```

`For` loop.

```
i=k=j=p=0
```

Start with `i` (\$=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}\$), `k` (number of duplicates found), `j` (\$=n\$), `p`(\$=a_{n-1}\$) equal to 0.

```
k<#
```

Repeat while `k` is less than the input.

```
i=i|p
```

Append `p` to `i` using the head `Alternatives` (a golfier version of `List` in this case).

```
p+=If[p>++j&&FreeQ[i,p-j],-j,j]
```

Increment `j`. If `p` is greater than `j` (i.e. \$a_{n-1} > n\$) and `p-j` is not in `i` (i.e. \$a_{n-1} - n\$ is new), then increment `p` by `-j`. Otherwise, increment `p` by `j`.

```
i~FreeQ~p||k++
```

Each iteration, increment `k` if `p` is not in `i` (the `||` (= `or`) short-circuits otherwise).

```
... ;p
```

Return `p`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
k=input();n=0;l=n,
while k:n+=1;x=l[-1]-n;u=x+2*n*(x<1or x in l);k-=u in l;l+=u,
print l[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoQgEAbge08xx8qEVTo1zZOEx4XE4U9CyZ7ehf1OX37LecH3niQi1zJODPmwCpbhOaN@KW0w4riJHtYFC67SjJ8xj213102NIkgnTlbqv6xG6jLkO6KQHgi9@/UH)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
n=input()
l=[];d=x=0
while n:d-=1;l+=x,d;x+=[d,-d][x+d in l];n-=x in l
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoAgDADQu1/hsTChog4l@xLxtkBhLAmj9fULeqdX35ZPnlUZCte7db0hiCkgCIzmyYUOyzt6mAI5kAGDOIg4eExRHNrCllJgD/LX1Ktws6K6LesH)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>56</s> <s>54</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes (SBCS)

*Saved <s>2</s> 7 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)*

```apl
0∘{×⍵:r,⍣d⊢(r,⍺)∇⍵-d←⍺∊⍨r←(⊃((≤∨⍺∊⍨-)⌷-,+)≢)⍺⋄⍬}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0edcyoPjz9Ue9WqyKdR72LUx51LdIAsXZpPupoBwrrpgDVAbmPOroe9a4oAnI0HnU1a2g86lzyqGMFXEJX81HPdl0dbc1HnYs0QaLdLY9619T@TwPr7gNqObTe@FHbRKDNwUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCkQEA)

Can be `f k`. Recursively builds up the first k duplicates.

⍺ holds Recamán's sequence (in reverse), and is set to 0 if no argument is given (at the start). If k (⍵) is 0, it returns an empty array (⍬). Otherwise, it computes the next term `r`. If `r` is present in ⍺, it calls itself with `r,⍺` as the left argument and `⍵-1` as the right argument, and prepends `r` to the result of that. If not, it just returns `(r,⍺) f ⍵`, hoping for the next iteration to find a duplicate.

`⎕IO←0` has to be used before using this, since it relies on 0-indexing.

````apl
0∘          ⍝ Default argument to start off the sequence
{×⍵:       ⍝ If k is greater than 1:
    r←(⊃((≤∨⍺∊⍨-)⌷-,+)≢)⍺
                       ≢     ⍝ Current n is the size of ⍺.
       ⊃                     ⍝ First element of ⍺ (a_{n-1})
                 ⌷           ⍝ Index into
                   -,+       ⍝ a_{n-1} - n, a_{n-1} + n using
         (≤∨⍺∊⍨-)           ⍝ another train to return 1 or 0
          ≤                  ⍝ If a_{n-1} is not greater than n
           ∨                 ⍝ or
               -             ⍝ a_{n-1} - n
            ⍺∊⍨             ⍝ is already in a,
                            ⍝ use a+n, otherwise a-n
    d←⍺∊⍨r                        ⍝ Whether or not r (a_n) is a duplicate

  (r,⍺)∇⍵-d                        
  (r,⍺)                           ⍝ Add r to ⍺, because it's part of Recaman's sequence
        ⍵-d                       ⍝ Decrement k if r is a duplicate
       ∇                          ⍝ Call itself, find the next duplicates

  r(,⍣d)(r,⍺)∇⍵-d
     ⍣d                           ⍝ If d is 0, just return (r,⍺)∇⍵-d
  r ,                             ⍝ Otherwise, add r to the list of duplicates (which is returned from (r,⍺)∇⍵-d

⋄⍬        ⍝ If k is 0, return an empty array
}
```
````

Comment: You can do `0∘{...}` to use 0 as a default left argument.

Comment: @ovs Oh, that's smart, thanks!

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0edcyoPjz9Ue9WqyINnUe9i1M0NYqA9C7NRx3tQFHdFKAyIPdRR9ej3hVFQI7Go65mDY1HnUsedayAS@hqPurZrqujrfmoc5EmSLS75VHvmtr/aWDdfUAth9YbP2qbCLQ4OMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwMgAA) by adding more trains ;). If you don't want to change the index origin, `r←(⊃(⊃(≤∨⍺∊⍨-)↓-,+)≢)⍺` works for 50 bytes.

Comment: @ovs Wow, thanks! I think I'll use the `⎕IO←0` version

Comment: `(,⍣d)` → `,⍣d⊢`

Comment: @Adám Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

Outputs the `nth` item `1-indexed`

```
¾ˆµ¯D¤N-DŠD0›*åN·*+©å½®Dˆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/8wNWFiMWX//8K@y4bCtcKvRMKkTi1ExaBEMOKAuirDpU7CtyorwqnDpcK9wq5Ey4b//zEw)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 59 bytes

Returns the **N-th** term, 0-indexed.

```javascript
i=>(g=x=>!g[x+=x>n&!g[x-n]?-n:n]||i--?g(g[n++,x]=x):x)(n=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclBC4IwGIDhe79iXWLDltvUQuGbP0R2ENOxkG@RETv431dRXpLe0wvPpX20U3dz1ztHf@7jANGBphYC6K1tQgJB4@59HE3NsUIzz47z2lLbYJLsg4HAqsAogmCx8zj5sT@M3tKBEiIYI2lKXuVq84vlgrJYoVQLquMKVfYfyzz/YiHL0wqLD0ohVBaf)

#### How?

We use **g()** as our main recursive function *and* as an object to keep track of the duplicates.

```javascript
i => (                    // given i
  g = x =>                // g = recursive function and generic object
    !g[x +=               // update x:
      x > n & !g[x - n] ? //   if x is greater than n and x - n was not visited so far:
        -n                //     subtract n from x
      :                   //   else:
        n                 //     add n to x
    ]                     // if x is not a duplicate
    || i-- ?              // or x is a duplicate but not the one we're looking for:
      g(g[n++, x] = x)    //   increment n, mark x as visited and do a recursive call
    :                     // else:
      x                   //   stop recursion and return x
)(n = 0)                  // initial call to g() with n = x = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
J]0@LJ.f}K+=G-eJZ*yZ|}GJ<G0~+JKQ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yvWwMHHSy@t1lvb1l031StKqzKqptbdy8bdoE7byzvQ8P9/IxMA)

Outputs the `n` first duplicates.

<sub>**waits for Jelly or one of the new stack languages to enter**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 160 bytes

```rust
|k|{let(mut a,mut r,mut n,mut i,mut v)=(vec!(0),0,1usize,0,0);while i<k{v=if v>n&&!a.contains(&(v-n)){v-n}else{v+n};if a.contains(&v){r=v;i+=1}a.push(v);n+=1}r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BjsIwDEX3nMJlUdmiVC2zIxPuUqFEWBSDkjQjEXL2kmY1mydb/1m23eLDagUeEwsSpB3AbALYM1hB/jkRHC@weH4b0Ovn/kklxccSYOo2ukqp5MpIGqO5NjhQN3RjHS3FQOrvxrMB/r2nqNlCvEjbNlN/fUooyz22GI9ClAqzmb1J8SBZFfO/Eyk5HRUf9Jin/rX4G0ZSsrUur6qcb58OGFhg7PvTUD8CeDmWMEuD@5T3HVhkok3Ou7x@AQ)

Ungolfed:

```rust
|k| {
  let mut a=vec!(0);
  let mut r=0;
  let mut n=1usize;
  let mut i=0;
  let mut v=r;
  while i < k {
    v = if v > n && !a.contains(&(v-n)) { 
      v - n
    } else { 
      v + n 
    };
    if a.contains(&v) {
      r = v;
      i += 1
    }
    a.push(v);
    n += 1
  }
  r
}
```