# Draw Recamán's sequence with ASCII

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, sequence

Recamán's sequence ([A005132](http://oeis.org/A005132)) is a mathematical sequence, defined as such:

$$A(n) = \begin{cases}0 & \textrm{if } n = 0 \\
A(n-1) - n & \textrm{if } A(n-1) - n \textrm{ is positive and not already in the sequence} \\
% Seems more readable than
%A(n-1) - n & \textrm{if } A(n-1) > n \wedge \not\exists m < n: A(m) = A(n-1)-n \\
A(n-1) + n & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

An alternative, simpler verbal explanation is as follows:

> Subtract unless you can't (the number is negative, or has been used before), in which case add.

The first few terms are \$0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11\$

Now, there is already [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/generaterecam%C3%A1ns-sequence) which asks you to generate the `n`th term of the sequence. This one is slightly different.

## Challenge

Given a number `n`, draw the first `n` terms of the sequence. What do I mean by 'draw'? Let me demonstrate:

1. Draw a number line `max([A(y) for y<=n])` units long. We'll assume `n` is 5, for now, so the number line is 6 units long (since the largest of \$A(1) = 0\$, \$A(2) = 1\$, \$A(3) = 3\$, \$A(4) = 6\$ and \$A(5) = 2\$ is \$6\$). Make the line from underscores, starting at 0:

`______`

2. Start with the transition between the first and second terms: that is, 0 and 1. Use `|` and `-` to draw a *square* (equal length and height), going upwards. In this case, we'll have to miss out the `-` because the distance is only 1.

```
||
______
```

3. Now, we'll draw on the next step (\$A(2) = 1\$ to \$A(3) = 3\$) on the bottom of the line (we alternate between up and down each time):

```
||
______
 | |
 |-|
```

As you can see, this line also has a height of 2, since the height must be equal to the distance between the two terms.

If we continue, we will eventually get to:

```
   |--|
   |  |
|| |  |
______
 |||  |
 |||  |
  |   |
  |---|
```

## Rules

- If there is a `-` and `|` colliding, the later one takes priority.
- There may be preceeding/trailing **spaces** before/after the image, but trailing/preceeding `_`s or `-`s are not allowed (exception is 0- or 1- indexing)
- You can choose to set the 0 point just before the first `_` on the number line, or just after it.
- No alternative characters for `-`, `|` or `_` may be used.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

## Test case

Here is another test case, with `n=10`

```
            |-------|
            ||-----||
            ||     ||
  |----|    ||     ||
  |    |    ||     ||
  ||--||    ||     ||
  ||  ||    ||     ||
||||  ||    ||     ||
_____________________
 |||  ||   |||     ||
 |||  ||   |||     ||
  |   ||   |||     ||
  |---||   |||     ||
       |   |||     ||
       |---|||     ||
           ||------||
           |--------|
```

Comment: It is not clear where left edge of square should be placed.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: basically, statement only specifies that we need to draw squares (width = height) and that they should alternate between up and down. There are no instructions about squares' size and position. In test case I see that 2 squares may have the same position of left edge.

Comment: I think `As you can see, this line also has a height of 2, since the height must be equal to the distance between the two terms.`, as well as `You can choose to set the 0 point just before the first _ on the number line, or just after it.` wrap this up pretty well.

Comment: I think the test case for n=10 is  wrong from 13-> 20 onwards.

Comment: Also one of your test cases and the description has the central line stop one space to the left of \$Max(A(n))\$ and the other test case it runs all the way to the right. My solution for now uses the second but I could easily change it.

Comment: `|--||----||--|_`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```
µ_ż+ɗLṪ>Ƈ-ḟ⁸Ḣṭµ¡µL;ⱮṀ’ṭr,;ɗƝJW,RN¹ƭƲ€$+Lp""ƲZẎ€Ʋ‘ŒṬ×"J$»/ị“-|_ ”Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AX8AgP9qZWxsef//wrVfxbwryZdM4bmqPsaHLeG4n@KBuOG4ouG5rcK1wqHCtUw74rGu4bmA4oCZ4bmtciw7yZfGnUpXLFJOwrnGrcay4oKsJCtMcCIixrJa4bqO4oKsxrLigJjFkuG5rMOXIkokwrsv4buL4oCcLXxfIOKAnVn//zEw)

A full program taking a single integer \$n\$ via STDIN and outputting the ASCII art based on zero-indexing.